# Unable to delete DNS forwarder in 2003 domain

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2003

I have an issue with deleting a forwarder in our Active Directory integrated DNS server, I get the following error:
The server forwarders cannot be updated.
Access was denied.

When I go to he security tap, select advanced and check the effective rights for my admin account, which has full control.
I tried googling to check, but have not been able to find any usefull tips.
The DNS domain does not exist anywhere else in DNS other than as a forwarder.

Comment: The last sentence confused me: "The DNS domain does not exist anywhere else in DNS other than as a forwarder." By *forwarder*, do you mean the IP address of a **server** that is configured on the Forwarders tab for the properties of a DNS server, or do you mean a **domain** that is configured somewhere else? Or are you looking at conditional forwarders?

Comment: It is a forwarder configured when looking in the properties of the DNS server.

Comment: This might be related: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/837335

Comment: Thanks for the tip, however the security settings already reflect the settings suggested.